# Using UIAlertController buttons to add custom cells to a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I have created a `UITableView` and created some cells and given them identifiers. I have also created a `UIAlertController` to display a popup when a button is pressed on the same `View Controller`. I would like to be able to insert new rows into the table with the appropriate cells depending on which button the user taps in the Alert popup. 
help?

Comment: When you "register the new cell content" from your `UIAlertController`, add it into your array/dictionary or whatever serves as your `UITableView` datasource. And call `yourTableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this way

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Test", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Row", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        tblView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.left)
        And update your data Sourse 
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i hope it will help you

Answer (score 2):

You can change as per section.

```
self.tblView.beginUpdates()
self.tblView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.yourArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
self.tblView.endUpdates()
```